# Pressing the ESC key right after calling RequestFullScreen breaks functionality

Tags: javascript

If I call RequestFullScreen on an element and press ESC at almost the exact same time, sometimes the promise returned from RequestFullScreen will be stuck as "pending" forever. The button I have assigned to call RequestFullScreen will not work again after this happens.

Is this a bug in Chrome? Or is there a way around this somehow?